# How to unit test a function inside a service in NestJs that sets expiry date based on current date

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, nestjs

So I am trying to write unit tests for a method inside a service that sets the expiry date based on the current date.

Condition: validTo date should be set to June 1st of this year if validFrom(today) is less than June 1st(let's say May 31st), else (let's say June 2nd), validTo date should be June 1st of next year(2022).

This is how the code looks like:

```
 public async setValidToDate(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      userCode.validFrom = moment().toDate();
      userCode.validTo = moment('06-01', 'MM-DD')
        .year(moment().year() + Number(moment().month() > 5))
        .toDate();
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(`Failed to set the date`);
    }
  }
```

I am wondering how can I mock the current date so that I can test this method. Because, whenever I'll call this service, it will always set the current date to today's date.

I am using Jest for my tests

Comment: are you using jest or what?

Comment: @MicaelLevi yes. I am using Jest

Comment: One option is to move the calculations of `validFrom` and `validTo` into separate functions, then you stub the functions in your test so they return known values. Another option is to stub the `moment` functions, though that ties your test to implementation detail.

Comment: I think this will help you: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#mock-timers

Comment: 1. Leave moment away - it's deprecated.
2. Use e.g. `date-fns`.
3. Mock single functions from used package in the given test suite.